# Generic TryParse extension method for the standard value types

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I often need to update properties using the `out` parameter of the standard `TryParse` methods. However, use of a property as `out` or `ref` parameter is not allowed. So, I wrote my own implementation of the `TryParse` method `MyTryParse` using the generic extension method, which is supposed to work for all standard value types.

**Codes:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Tester().TestIt();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Tester
{
    public bool BooleanP { get; set; } = true;
    public char CharP { get; set; } = 'A';
    public int IntP { get; set; } = 123;
    public double DoubleP { get; set; } = 3.14;
    public DateTime DateTimeP { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public struct TestStruct
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
    };
    public TestStruct StructP { get; set; }

    public void TestIt()
    {
        try
        {
            // bool.TryParse("TRUE", out BooleanP); // ERROR: A property or indexer may not be passed as out or ref parameter

            // bool
            BooleanP = BooleanP.MyTryParse("bad");
            BooleanP.PPrint("\nBooleanP");

            BooleanP = BooleanP.MyTryParse("FALSE");
            BooleanP.PPrint("BooleanP");

            // char
            CharP = CharP.MyTryParse("xx");
            CharP.PPrint("\nCharP");

            CharP = CharP.MyTryParse("Y");
            CharP.PPrint("CharP");

            // int
            IntP = IntP.MyTryParse("0.1");
            IntP.PPrint("\nIntP");

            IntP = IntP.MyTryParse("555");
            IntP.PPrint("IntP");

            // double
            DoubleP = DoubleP.MyTryParse("3xxx");
            DoubleP.PPrint("\nDoubleP");

            DoubleP = DoubleP.MyTryParse("3.1415");
            DoubleP.PPrint("DoubleP");

            // DateTime
            DateTimeP = DateTimeP.MyTryParse("20180707");
            DateTimeP.PPrint("\nDateTimeP");

            DateTimeP = DateTimeP.MyTryParse("2018.07.07");
            DateTimeP.PPrint("DateTimeP");

            // struct
            Console.WriteLine();
            StructP = StructP.MyTryParse("9", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    private enum StandardTtype
    {
        Undefined,
        Boolean,
        Byte, SByte,
        Char,
        Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64,
        Single, Double, Decimal, DateTime
    };

    public static T MyTryParse<T>(this T value, string text, bool throwEx = false) where T : struct
    {
        object oVal = value;
        string typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        StandardTtype type = StandardTtype.Undefined;
        Enum.TryParse(typeName, out type);
        switch (type)
        {
            case StandardTtype.Boolean:
                {
                    if (bool.TryParse(text, out bool outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Byte:
                {
                    if (byte.TryParse(text, out byte outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.SByte:
                {
                    if (sbyte.TryParse(text, out sbyte outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Char:
                {
                    if (char.TryParse(text, out char outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Int16:
                {
                    if (short.TryParse(text, out short outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.UInt16:
                {
                    if (ushort.TryParse(text, out ushort outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Int32:
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(text, out int outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.UInt32:
                {
                    if (uint.TryParse(text, out uint outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Int64:
                {
                    if (long.TryParse(text, out long outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.UInt64:
                {
                    if (ulong.TryParse(text, out ulong outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Single:
                {
                    if (float.TryParse(text, out float outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Double:
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(text, out double outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Decimal:
                {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(text, out decimal outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.DateTime:
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out DateTime outVal))
                        oVal = outVal;
                    else ThrowException();
                }
                break;
            case StandardTtype.Undefined:
            default:
                if (throwEx)
                    throw new Exception($"The type '{typeName}' is unhandled");
                break;
        }

        try
        {
            value = (T)oVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (throwEx)
                throw new Exception($"Cannot convert '{oVal.ToString()}' into '{typeName}'", ex);
        }

        void ThrowException()
        {
            if (throwEx)
                throw new Exception($"Cannot parse \"{text}\" into `{typeName}`");
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static void PPrint<T>(this T value, string name = "value")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " = " + value );
    }
}
```

The main purpose of this method is to work quietly (unless I tell to do otherwise) and update properties (or fields) if this is possible.

**Question:** Is something in the `MyTryParse` method which can go wrong?

Any other suggestion for improving performance, style of readability would be very welcome.

Comment: Could you post an example of your real problem and explain why this is a problem, I mean a case of: _I often need to update properties using the `out` parameter of the standard_ because this code it one of the most unconventional and confusing ways of solving something that probalby should be solved in a completely different way. To me it's a clear case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @t3chb0t I didn't knew about the XY problem. Thanks for that.. my problem is that: `bool.TryParse("TRUE", out BooleanP);` is not allowed, where `BooleanP` is the property. I have it commented in my `TestIt()` method. I am trying to update a property from a string value with a single simple command like the  `bool.Parse("TRUE");`. Except the last one throws an exception if it is not successful.

Comment: The question is still why are you doing this? Why do you want to use a property there? This is pretty unusual and this is your problem Y that's why I'm asking ;-) you are not telling us about the actual issue, your problem X.

Comment: Because in my WinForms applications when a user changes some control's text to update the corresponding auto property. if parsing is possible.

Comment: Now we're talking! ;-) could add an example of how you are using this solution in your application? A real-world snippet would be great.

Comment: I can't see where are we going... For example this one: `private void RateMSI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var _rate = Rate;
             double.TryParse(RateValMSI.Text, out _rate);
             Rate = _rate;
        }`

Comment: @L_J: if processing user input is the main use-case for this code, then I guess you're not familiar with data binding?

Comment: We're going towards the real issue that you are trying to solve here (in a wrong way) but you seem to want to keep the current solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Trying to put all this type-specific code into a single 'generic' method requires runtime type checks and boxing/unboxing. You're paying for this at runtime, but what do you gain from it? Writing several type-specific methods seems more appropriate here. You would have to write multiple overloads anyway if you want to provide additional parsing settings (such as number styles or exact date formats).
- Making this an extension method is confusing: `this T value` is actually used as a fallback value for when exception throwing is disabled, it's not really 'operating' on the given value. `ID = ID.TryParse(input);` is short, but it's not very clear what's going on - why are you calling a parse method on something that you're also assigning to? I'd probably go for something like `ID = Util.TryParse(input, fallbackValue: ID);` - more writing, but also easier to understand.
- If you must perform runtime type checks, then don't use `Type.Name`: that will fail for user-made types with perfectly valid names like `Boolean` or `Int32`. `Type.FullName` should be more reliable, but why not just compare against `typeof(bool)` and the like, or use `Type.GetTypeCode(t)`, which gives you a `TypeCode` enum?

---

You've essentially written a method that can either return a fallback value or throw an exception on failure - it's `Parse` and `TryParse` in one:

```
public static bool TryParse(string input, bool fallbackValue = false, bool throwOnFailure = false)
{
    if (throwOnFailure)
        return bool.Parse(input);
    else
        return bool.TryParse(input, out var result) ? result : fallbackValue;
}

// repeat for other (commonly used) types
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, that I hardly can imagine where to use a default value (the current value of a property) if a conversion of string input fails? When say `IntP.TryParse("0.1")` fails with `throwEx = false` you'll get back `IntP = 123` - without any warning and therefore any knowledge of the error. This can lead to "fatalities" of any kind in a program and no one will know. You should not do that. If a conversion fails you should certainly inform the user or log the failure in some way.